# Is it safe to store authorization flags in redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, authorization

I am new to react and redux, and am creating a react app that needs to have routes based on the user's role like student or teacher. Currently, I use a component to conditionally create routes based on the status of the user:

```
// AppRouter.js

const AppRouter = () => (
      <Router history={history}>
        <div>
          <Header />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/Login" component={LoginPage} exact={true} />
            <ProtectedRoutes />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>

//ProtectedRoutes.js

const ProtectedRoutes = (props) => {
  const isStudent = props.isStudent;
  const isTeacher = props.isTeacher;

  const studentRoutes = [
    <Route key={1} path="/StudentHub" component={StudentHubPage} />,
    <Route key={2} path="/Assignment" component={AssignmentPage} />
  ];
  const teacherRoutes = [
    <Route key={1} path="/TeacherHub" component={TeacherHubPage} />,
    <Route key={2} path="/CreateCourse" component={CreateCourse} />
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {isStudent && studentRoutes}
      {isTeacher && teacherRoutes}
    </div>
  );
};


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isStudent: state.isStudent,
  isTeacher: state.isTeacher
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProtectedRoutes);
```

My back-end API implements JWT for authentication. During the login process I would set the `isStudent` and `isTeacher` flags in my store based on what I get back from my API after loging in. The API already checks for roles from the auth token every time I make a request, so there isn't an issue for the back-end.

My question is, is this the proper and safe way of storing and checking user roles and creating routes? Would a user be able to manipulate or change my redux store and change these values to create unauthorized routes?

Comment: users of your site can literally do anything with your javascript. there's basically nothing you can do to secure anything in client side javascript whatsoever. focus on making the user experience nice, and your back end very secure

Comment: @azium do you think it would be better to make an API call in my `ProtectedRoutes` component to check for roles instead of keeping it on the front-end?

Comment: can't say whether its better or not. it depends on what your security need are. typically it doesn't really matter what gets displayed on the screen. you just want to make sure that network traffic only carries information to clients that have the correct roles / authorization

Comment: You can check your auth token from server side in the ProtectedRoutes

Comment: @azium I understand what you are saying and I make sure not to send data to unauthorized users from the back-end. The only thing is, my menu options in my header need to display different options for students and teachers. This was the only way I could think of doing it.

Comment: yeah that's fine. I mean there are more elegant ways of doing conditional rendering, but it's perfectly fine how you have done it